# vue-hot-reload-api stopping serve from building

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an app that i am trying to run on the vue/cli development server. I try to either run `npm run serve` or use `vue ui` then run it through that.

Every time i try to run it my command line stops at this and doesn't continue building the app:

```
$ vue-cli-service serve --mode development --dashboard
 INFO  Starting development server...

 25% building 127/140 modules 13 active ...odules\vue-hot-reload-api\dist\index.js
```

It is almost always `vue-hot-reload-api`, with the exception being `axios`. What can you suggest for trying to fix this? I can't find a fix anywhere, not even on the vue git issues pages.

(I can't make vue or vuejs a tag :/)

Thanks in advance for any help!